# Is it possible to mock a function in all mounted components for every test file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

Here is an example of a test file:

```js
it('test case 1', () => {
       wrapper = shallowMount(Login, {
         store,
        localVue,
        mocks: {
           $router
           $GlobalVarForAllComponents // i want this variable to be assigned to every component i mock globally
         }
       })
       expect(true).to(true)
})
```

I want the `$GlobalVarForAllComponents` to be automatically assigned to every test case I write, without having to explicitly write this for every single test. Is it possible to use a global setting to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the jest.init.js file
config.mocks['$store'] = {
state: {
id: 1
}
}

https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/config.html